# VScode intellisense for paths not working for paths in my nested tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, path, intellisense, tsconfig

I have a project structured like this:

```
<project root>
|-- tsconfig.json // let's call it the root tsconfig
|-- lib
|   |-- foo.ts
|-- app
|   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |-- app.tsx
```

the root tsconfig is like

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "paths": {
      "/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*"
  ]
}
```

And the app tsconfig is like:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve",
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*",
  ]
}
```

However when I try to import `lib/foo` from `app/app` like

```
import { foo } from '/lib/foo'
```

Vscode intellisense won't jump out and give me a list of files to import. There won't be any errors after I manually filled in the path, and it can even jump. Both tsc (there is a noEmit but it is happy with the types) and esbuild are happy too.

I tried other paths than `/*` since vscode is thinking I am referring to the real `/` when I typed it, however it does not work either. Again tsc and esbuild are happy, and vscode is happy when I filled in the path, but intellisense is not.

How can I make intellisense work ?

I am on code 1.77.3, typescript 5.0.4.

Comment: aren't you supposed to use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) for these sorts of things?

Comment: No because I use esbuild and I won't use another plugin just for that. And because this is just a part of it, there are 5 different tsconfig in the project all extending the root one. And because that `/lib` is a shared source library, it makes no sense to compile by itself.